# How to change between QML views dynamically

Tags: python, qt, qml, qtquick2, pyside2

The behavior I want to achieve is by selecting from a dropdown box, you will see a different QML component. So if the user selects "Apple" then the Apple component will be viewed, otherwise the "Banana" component would be viewed. My approach so far is to use a ListView with a Loader delegate as follows, however my components are not displayed at all. Is there a better way of achieving the behaviour I'm after?

view.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: page
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    ColumnLayout {

        ListModel {
            id: nullmodel
        }

        ComboBox {
            id: selector
            currentIndex: 1
            model: ListModel {
                id: cbItems
                ListElement { text: "Apple"; }
                ListElement { text: "Banana"; }
            }
            onCurrentIndexChanged: viewer.selected = cbItems.get(currentIndex).text
        }

        ListView {
            model: nullmodel
            id: viewer
            property string selected: "Apple" 

            delegate: Loader {

                sourceComponent: {

                    switch(selected)
                    {
                        case "Apple": {
                            console.log("Apples!")
                            return Apple
                        }
                        case "Banana": {
                            console.log("Bananas!")
                            return Banana
                        }
                        default:
                            console.log("Neither")
                           return Apple
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Apple.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {

    Text {
        text: "Hi, I'm an Apple"
    }
}
```

Banana.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
    Text {
        text: "Hi, I'm a Banana"
    }
}
```

If its of any relevance, I'm using PySide2 to display

main.py

```
import sys
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    qmlFile = join(dirname(__file__), 'view.qml')
    engine.load(abspath(qmlFile))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
ColumnLayout {

    ComboBox {
        id: selector

        model: ListModel {
            id: cbItems
            ListElement { text: "Apple"; }
            ListElement { text: "Banana"; }
        }

        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            viewer.source = cbItems.get(currentIndex).text + ".qml";
        }
    }

    Loader {
        y: 50
        id: viewer
        source: "Apple.qml"

        onSourceChanged: {
            console.log(source);
        }
    }
}
```

To achieve your goal, lonely `Loader` is enough. However you can place it wherever you want eg. in `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks that was it!

Comment: Good answer. A StackLayout can be useful in this case also when you want to preserve state when switching back and forth (versus reinstantiating the component each time you switch).